# Connecting RStudio to DashDB in the IBM Watson Studio

Tags: rstudio, dashdb, data-science-experience, watson-studio

How do I connect R Studio to DashDb inside IBM Watson Studio?

Comment: The question is pretty broad. Be more specific or it will be closed.

Comment: There's actually a tutorial called, surprise, "Using dashDB with RStudio in Data Science Experience". I think it might be worth checking out.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way of connecting dashDB with RStudio is using the `ibmdbR` package. Here, is a link to the tutorial (as already mentioned in comments by @mustaccio) http://datascience.ibm.com/blog/dashdb-r-dsx/

Answer (score 1):

Some more samples are linked from here: http://datascience.ibm.com/blog/working-with-dashdb-in-data-science-experience/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys.  I really appreciate the responses.  Looks like you can do it via an ODBC connection as well.  This worked well for me because I speak SQL better than R.

Just make sure that the field names are all capitalized in the database.  I ran into issues because the sql query has to be surrounded by quotes and non-capitalized field names in DashDB sql also require quotes.  The over abundance of quotes caused the sqlQuery(myconn, ("query")) to blow up.
There may be another way to deal with it, but capitalizing the fields in the database worked for me.

```
library(RODBC)

 dsn_driver <- "BLUDB" 
 dsn_database <- "BLUDB"  
 dsn_hostname <- "hostname"  
 dsn_port <- "50000"  
dsn_protocol <- "TCPIP"  
dsn_uid <- "userid"  
dsn_pwd <- "pw"

 conn_path <- paste(dsn_driver,  
               ";DATABASE=",dsn_database,
               ";HOSTNAME=",dsn_hostname,
               ";PORT=",dsn_port,



               ";PROTOCOL=",dsn_protocol,
               ";UID=",dsn_uid,
               ";PWD=",dsn_pwd,sep="")



 myconn <-odbcConnect(conn_path)

 df_out <- sqlQuery(myconn, ("type your sql query between the quotes"))
```